# Custom JavaScript different in page source than in file as pasted

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

In my Joomla (1.5) installation I'm getting errors presumably because the JS code as it's pasted into the index.php file (above `</head>`) is somehow changed when I look at the page source.

This is a set of screenshots of what's going on:

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can see my code is saying `src="undefined"!==typeof`, while the page source is saying `src="/undefined"!==typeof`.

I tried changing `src="/undefined"!==typeof` to `src=typeof MIX...!=='undefined'?==typeof` but it didn't help.

I get this in firebug:

> ReferenceError: MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL is not defined

It's my analytics code for MixPanel, & it doesn't report page loads to my dashboard. I don't know how to get it to work.

Comment: Try to remove typeof so it looks like  a.src="undefined" != MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL ? MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL : "fil.......

Answer (score 0):

I think the real issue is with joomla parsing the source index.php and converting that quote to a backslash for some reason. I am not a joomly kind of person, but I offer you these potential hacks to try to fix it quickly:

Try putting parenthesis around the whole expression up until the semicolon.

```
a.src=("undefined"!==typeof..........);
```

Another hack... get rid of the ternary operator check for the variable, and always just define a.src using the else part from the original expression:

```
a.src="file:"===e.location.protocol......;
```

Comment: Someone from#javascript IRC solved it for me with this: src = typeof MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL !== 'undefined' ? MIXPANEL_CUSTOM_LIB_URL : "file:"===e.location.

Comment: @cdvonstinkpot Awesome! :)